# NotMapped attribute issue with Odata version 8.2.3, unable to filter the data using notmapped field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, odata, .net-8.0

[NotMapped] attribute issue with Odata version 8.2.3, unable to filter the data using notmapped field.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Name", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("ShortName", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Description", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Status", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public WorksWarefx.Core.Enums.RecordStatus Status { get; set; } =    WorksWarefx.Core.Enums.RecordStatus.active;

    
    [NotMapped]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("StatusId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int StatusId
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)Status;
        }
    }

}
```

EDM model registered as below.

```
StructuralTypeConfiguration<Customer> customer = builder.EntitySet<Customer>(nameof(Customer)).EntityType;
customer.Property(c => c.StatusId);
```

Below is the exception thrown by LINQ,

```
Error Name : System.InvalidOperationException
Error Message : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Customer>()
.Where(s => s.StatusId == __TypedProperty_0)' could not be 
translated. Additional information: Translation of member `'StatusId' on entity type 'Customer' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

Exception Type : System.InvalidOperationException
```

response for this always helpful..

we tried removing the EDM model

```
"EntityType.Count().Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand(9)"
```

from the registry but didn't work.

Comment: Hi,@Raagi Shiva ,could you show your uri and the related codes in controller ,so that we could  reproduce the issue?

Comment: uri: https://localhost:****/api/v1/customer?$filter=StatusId eq 1,

controller code sample:


[HttpGet] 
[EnableQuery]
public Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> Get()
{
    return _implementation.GetAllAsync();
}

here _implementation is a reference to our repository, where data is retrieved.

public Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>(_context.Customer);
}

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/fundamentals/query-options?tabs=net60):

> The EnableQuery attribute is an action filter that parses, validates,
> and applies the query. The filter converts the query options into a
> LINQ (Language-Integrated Query) expression. When the controller
> returns an IQueryable or IActionResult type, the LINQ provider
> converts the LINQ expression into a query, e.g., Entity Framework (EF)
> Core will convert the LINQ expression into an SQL statement.

In your case,you returned a OkObject result,if you try with your filter,it would be trasnlated into linq like:

```
_context.Customer.Where(x => x.StatusId == 1);
```

However,there's no StatusId column in db, so it counldn't be translated to sql

```
SELECT ... FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE STATUSId =...
```

You could try configure ComputedColumn in dbcontext instead of NotMapped

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.StatusId).HasComputedColumnSql("[Status]");
}
```

It could work now:

[image]